# draggable div getting dragged when input range slider is used

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a draggable div which can be dragged and place in a different position of a list. Inside this div i have used a input range. When i slide this range, my div also getting dragged.I have tried using `stopPropagation` to my range but i did not prevent my div from getting dragged when using the range slider.

This is my overall div that can be dragged and the input range slider is used inside this div

```
<li class="column" draggable="true" id="{{layer.alternate|slice:'8:'}}">
   <div class="inserted-card noprint" style="padding: 1rem" id="{{layer.title|cut:" "}}">
   <div class="layer-card">
      <div class="pt-3 d-flex justify-content-end"
         style="width: 100%;text-align: right;">
         <div style="padding: 1rem; display: flex;justify-content: space-between">
            <h4 class="mr-4 base-layer-title">Opacity </h4>
            <input type="range" name="yearInputName" onchange="changeOpacity({{layer.alternate|slice:'8:'}},{{layer.title|cut:" "}})"
            id="opacity{{layer.alternate|slice:'8:'}}" value="100" min="0" max="100">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

CSS for the draggable div

```
[draggable] {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */
    -khtml-user-drag: element;
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
  }
  
  #columns {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: move;
  }
  .column.dragElem {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .column.over {
    /* border: 2px dashed #000; */
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
  }
```

Comment: try with `stopImmediatePropagation`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get a point from this pseudocode.

```
draggableElement.onclick = (event)=> {
     if(event.target == rangeInputElement)
        draggableElement.draggable = false;
     else
        draggableElement.draggable = true; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and solved it this way:

1. Set "draggable" attribute to "true" for range input.
2. Add "dragstart" event listener for range input.
3. Call e.preventDefault() inside that event listener.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and the answer by @vdem this code fixed my range slider drag issue when inside a draggable element:

```js
jQuery('input[type="range"]').on('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" class="slider" draggable="true">
```